# UserControl positioning understanding

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls

I'm getting close to the understanding of the positioning of the `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl` objects:
By default, they don't have X or Y coordinates, relative to their container, but there is the possibility to add some, using so-called "Attached Properties".
A typical example of such attached properties are `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, which mean that, in case the container of the `UserControl` is a `Canvas`, then the following happens with (supposingly) its upper left point (pseudo-code):

```
UserControl_UpperLeft_Point.X = Canvas.Left
UserControl_UpperLeft_Point.Y = Canvas.Top
```

Now what I'd like to know:

- Is my idea correct? Is it indeed the upper left corner which is used?
- What if I want to modify this behaviour, let's say into:

  ```
  int left_Margin = 100;
  int top_Margin  = 200;
  UserControl_UpperLeft_Point.X = Canvas.Left / 2 + left_Margin; 
  UserControl_UpperLeft_Point.Y = Canvas.Top  * 2 + top_Margin;
  ```
- What if I want to position my `UserControl`, based on the upper right corner or even the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my idea correct? Is it indeed the upper left corner which is used?

It is *effectively* the upper left corner in this case, but actually each of the *sides* are aligned. Furthermore, the control is aligned by the `Canvas`, it does not have internal X or Y coordinates that are set. They are given by the attached properties which are sepcific to the `Canvas`, no other panel. The `Canvas` internally calculates a rectangle where it draws the `UserControl`.

- [`Canvas.Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas.left?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

  > Gets or sets a value that represents the distance between the *left side* of an element and the left side of its parent Canvas.
- [`Canvas.Top`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas.top?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

  > Gets or sets a value that represents the distance between the top of an element and the top of its parent Canvas.

It is also important to note, that there is a [priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas.top?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) for the attached properties.

> If you specify them, the attached properties Canvas.Top or Canvas.Left take priority over Canvas.Bottom or Canvas.Right.

---

> What if I want to modify this behaviour, let's say into: [...]

You would still have to assign the attached properties, but calculate the expression before.

- Use a `Binding` or `MultiBinding` with a custom value converter that evaluates an expression that is bound or passed as converter parameter or with a specialized value converter to calculate a specific term.
- Create your own specialized attached properties that internally assign the calculated value to the `Canvas` attached properties.

---

> What if I want to position my UserControl, based on the upper right corner

Set the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Right` attached properties instead.

```
<Canvas>
   <local:MyUserControl Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Right="0" Width="50" Height="80"/>
</Canvas>
```

> [...] or even the center?

A `Canvas` is used for absolute positioning. If you want to center controls, a `Grid` might be the better choice. If you still want to use a `Canvas` and it is fixed size, just calculate the center coordinates yourself and set the attached properties accordingly. If it is resizeable and the position of the `UserControl` position needs to be responsive to that, you could do one of these.

- Put a `Grid` around the `Canvas` and put the `UserControl` *after* it. It will appear on top of the `Canvas` and will be centered automatically, even on resizing.

  ```
  Grid>
     <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="20" Fill="Black" Width="50" Height="50"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="300" Canvas.Left="230" Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="80"/>
     </Canvas>
     <local:MyUserControl Width="50" Height="80"/>
  </Grid>
  ```
- Implement a custom behavior or complicated bindings with converter using the bound `ActualSize` of the `Canvas` to set the attached properties, which I **do not recommend**.

I think for your last question it is more useful to ask *why* you need this behavior, *what* you want to achieve. Often there is a much simpler and more suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position a control inside a container you should follow the WPF way.

[image]

Align it horizontal and vertical and set the margin, thats it.

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
      <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
      <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>

  <!--#region top-->
  <Border
    Margin="20,20,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock>
      Top<LineBreak />
      Left</TextBlock>
  </Border>

  <Border
    Margin="0,20,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock>
      Top<LineBreak />
      Center</TextBlock>
  </Border>

  <Border
    Margin="0,20,20,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock>
      Top<LineBreak />
      Right</TextBlock>
  </Border>
  <!--#endregion-->

  <!--#region center-->
  <Border
    Margin="20,0,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock>
      Center<LineBreak />
      Left</TextBlock>
  </Border>

  <Border
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock>
      Center<LineBreak />
      Center</TextBlock>
  </Border>

  <Border
    Margin="0,0,20,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock>
      Center<LineBreak />
      Right</TextBlock>
  </Border>
  <!--#endregion-->

  <!--#region bottom-->
  <Border
    Margin="0,0,20,20"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBlock>
      Bottom<LineBreak />
      Right</TextBlock>
  </Border>

  <Border
    Margin="0,0,0,20"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBlock>
      Bottom<LineBreak />
      Center</TextBlock>
  </Border>

  <Border
    Margin="20,0,0,20"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBlock>
      Bottom<LineBreak />
      Left</TextBlock>
  </Border>
  <!--#endregion-->

</Grid>
```

If you want to have the *old* style (knwon from WinForms you can align it `HorizontalAlignemnt="Top"` and `VerticalAlignment="Left"` and use the `Left` and `Top` property of `Margin` to set the old school `Left` and `Top`.